# How can I change the color of a \enquote quotation inside Emacs?

Tags: emacs, auctex, csquotes

When I paste a text inside quotation marks into Emacs+AUCTeX, AUCTeX formats it with a soft red color (see the screenshot below at the first line).

I like this color. However, I'm using `csquotes` package to handle (multilingual) quotations marks. The `\enquote` commands (provided by `csquote` package) use another color. I don't like this last color (see screenshot at the second line). With this ugly soft green color, I cannot find quickly quotation inside a big document.

How can I change `csquotes` default color to use AUCTeX default one?

### The screenshot:

[image]

(This screenshot uses French quotation marks but it hasn't any influence on my question.)

There is a bunch of settings about fontification in the csquotes.el file but I didn't see any reference to colors:

```
  ;; Fontification
   (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
          (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("DisableQuotes" "")
                ("RestoreQuotes" ""))
                  'function)
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("enquote" "*{")
                ("foreignquote" "*{{")
                ("hyphenquote" "*{{")
                ("textcquote" "*[[{[{")
                ("foreigntextcquote" "*{[[{[{")
                ("hyphentextcquote" "*{[[{[{")
                ("textquote" "*[[{")
                ("foreigntextquote" "*{[[{")
                ("hyphentextquote" "*{[[{")
                ("blockquote" "[[{")
                ("foreignblockquote" "{[[{")
                ("hyphenblockquote" "{[[{")
                ("blockcquote" "[[{[{")
                ("foreignblockcquote" "{[[{[{")
                ("hyphenblockcquote" "{[[{[{"))
                  'textual)
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("setquotestyle" "[{")
                ("MakeOuterQuote" "{")
                ("MakeInnerQuote" "{")
                ("MakeAutoQuote" "*{{")
                ("MakeForeignQuote" "*{{{")
                ("MakeHyphenQuote" "*{{{")
                ("MakeBlockQuote" "{{{")
                ("MakeForeignBlockQuote" "{{{{")
                ("MakeHyphenBlockQuote" "{{{{")
                ("DeclareQuoteStyle" "[{[[{[{[{[{")
                ("DeclareQuoteAlias" "[{{")
                ("DeclareQuoteOption" "{")
                ("DeclarePlainStyle" "{{{{")
                ("SetBlockThreshold" "{")
                ("SetBlockEnvironment" "{")
                ("SetCiteCommand" "{"))
                  'variable)))))

;;; csquotes.el ends here
```

Comment: How about considering adding `\enquote` to the *font* command, like `\emph` etc. Then you can also give it a nice shortcut. That is the `LaTeX-font-list` variable. That being said, I do not know how to change the font on it. It ought to be there somewhere since Emacs know to format `\textbf` and `\emph` differently.

Comment: @daleif I don't need a shortcut (I can call `\enquote` by pressing " twice). I can add `enquote` to `LaTeX-font-list` but I don't know (either) how to set a color to this command...

Comment: How did you get the double `"` shortcut? I like the font listfeature as it makes it easy to change the macro or remove it. There is some info about the fonts used in `latex-font.el` in the auctex sources.

Comment: @daleif It is a feature of AUCTeX/csquotes. See [the doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html) The setting is: LaTeX-csquotes-quote-after-quote

Comment: The hint is in the section of code you provided in the question -- `enquote` is assigned a property value of `'textual`.  If you search the source-code for `latex-font.el` as @daleif indicated, you will find the section of code that uses `font-lock-type-face`.  Did you try placing your cursor on the color you want to change and type?:  `C-u C-x =`  If you did that, did the information window say `font-lock-type-face` was a face at that particular point?  And if it said that, did you try changing the color for `font-lock-type-face` using `M-x customize-face RET font-lock-type-face RET`

Comment: Here is the link to the same thread on emacs.stackexchange:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9349/2287